# Tricky combinatorial number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$100$ blocks are selected from a crate containing 33 blocks of each of the following dimensions: $13 \times 17 \times 21$, $13 \times 17 \times 37$, $13 \times 21 \times 37$, and $17 \times 21 \times 37$. The chosen blocks are stacked on top of each other (one per cross section) forming a tower of height $h$. Compute the number of possible values of $h$.

I haven't got very far with this problem. All I know is that $h$ is of the form $13a+17b+21c+37d$ and the problem comes down to finding restrictions on $a,b,c,d$. I am trying to think how to exploit the symmetry in the problem. Also I am unsure of how to deal with "repeats" - $13a+17b+21c+37d$ may assume the same value for different ordered   quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: Instead of using $x$ in dimensions, use, e.g., `3\times 4` to get $3\times 4$.

Comment: You don't need to write $13x17$, using the letter $x$ that way; you can write $13\times17$.  I changed it.

Comment: Not completely sure how to solve this but, although it may be true for a given combination, I don't think $13a +...$ will help you solve it. I think need to think in terms of sets and subtract/possibly add back overlaps.  One overlap being e.g. adding of heights $13,17$ and $17,13$.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

The differences between your four dimensions are all multiples of four. So given any arrangement of 100 blocks, you can adjust any one block and change the height of the entire collection buy multiples of four.

So your stack of minimum height is given by $13\cdot 99+17= 1304$ and your maximum height is $37\cdot 99+21=3684$ and most of the multiples of 4 are attainable. The problem is when your stack contains mostly 21's and 37's. Some of the multiples of four towards the high end of the range are not obtainable.

Update: The more I think about it, every multiple of 4 should be obtainable. I'm driving right now so I can't put pencil to paper yet, but hopefully this will get you going.

Update: What do you know about generating functions?

Comment: Yes this is a good start. I found the minimum and maximum but I didn't realize the multiples of 4 thing.

Comment: I know about generating functions and how to apply them to combinatorics problems. I didn't think to use this but I think I see how. Consider the expansion $(ax^{13}+bx^{17}+cx^{21})^{33}$ and the analogous ones for the other boxes. Multiply together all the expansions. After grouping terms of equal degree we want get terms of the form $a^xb^yc^zd^wx^i$ times some coefficient maybe. We want the number of terms with $z+y+z+w=100$. Now this generating function is waaaay to complicated but thats the general idea. Do you have a better function in mind?

Comment: Also for the other method (which is probably better). You can make adjustments like: $b$->$b+1$, $a$->$a-1$ and $b$->$b-1$, $c$->$c+1$ to increase the height of the stack by exactly $4$, but you can only do this roughly $2*98=196$ times. You can do similar things to get multiples of $8$ and $16$. But also, not all heights differ by multiples of 4. I really wish I could think more logically/systematically about this, its a nice problem. I'm trying to improve at combinatorics.

Comment: Maybe starting smaller will help. Suppose there's $k$ blocks of each type and we draw $3k+1$ blocks. Let $k=1$ and see what happens. It might also be easier to let the blocks have dimension 0,4,8, or 24 in place of 13, 17, 21, and 37.

Comment: Following my own advice, I let $k=1$ and using 0,4,8, and 24 as dimensions with one of each type, 68 is impossible!

Comment: What about the generating functions? What is your idea there?

Comment: I can't figure it out ... Yet!

Answer (score 0):

I found a generating function that will work! We need two variables; the variable $u$ will count the inclusion of a block in our stack and the variable $z$ will track which dimension of the block we include in our stack. Thus
$$
(1+uz^{13}+uz^{17}+uz^{21})^{33}(1+uz^{13}+uz^{17}+uz^{37})^{33}(1+uz^{13}+uz^{21}+uz^{37})^{33}(1+uz^{17}+uz^{21}+uz^{37})^{33}
$$
is the generating function we want. In particular, the coefficient of $u^{100}$ will be a polynomial in $z$ whose exponents will be all the possible heights.

Computationally, this is a beast. Maple (implemented on my laptop) gave up on it.

Comment: Ahhhhh. This is the generating function I originally thought of but I forget the constant term in each expansion, so I thought the $u$'s would produce no useful information. Of course this is the generating function we are interested in! But I think the solution to this problem is more along the lines you originally suggested.

Comment: I ran some smaller versions along the lines of having $k$ in each collection and sampling $3k+1$ and there was always exactly one possible height missing. In particular, it isn't too difficult to show that $3672$ isn't possible. But I am not sure how to demonstrate all the others are possible. Good luck!